# Probability in a small interval is $P. dx$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, mathematics

Reif says

> ... variable $u$ which can assume any value in the continuous range $a_{1}<u<a_{2}$. To give a probability description of such a situation, one can focus attention on any infinitesimal range of the variable between $u$ and $u+d u$ and ask for the probability that the variable assumes a value in this range. One expects that this probability is proportional to the magnitude of $d u$ if this interval is sufficiently small;

> - Indeed, the probability must be expressible as a Taylor's series in powers of du and must vanish as $d u \rightarrow 0$. Hence the leading term must be of the form $P d u$, while terms involving higher powers of $d u$ are negligible if $d u$ is sufficiently small.

So expanding probability function as Taylor series I've

$P(x+d x)=P(x)+\frac{P^{\prime}(x)}{1 !} d x+\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(x)}{2 !} d x^{2}+\cdots$

in limit $dx$ is small we've

$P(x+d x)=P(x)+{P'(x)} d x$

Now how do I make the connection that "probability is proportional to the magnitude of $d x$ if this interval is sufficiently small"?

Comment: It looks like you are confusing the cumulative distribution function (CDF) $P(x)$ with the probability density function (PDF) $p(x).$ The relationship is $P(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x p(y)\,dy.$ Then $P(x+dx)-P(x)\approx p(x)dx$ is the probability to be in the interval $[x,x+dx]$.

Comment: No, the author says it's probability,

Comment: Which autor, what "it" ? You wrote yourself correctly $P(x+dx)-P(x)=P\color{red}{'}(x)\,dx$. In other words, probability $P(x+dx)-P(x)$ is proportional to $dx$. Factor of proportionality is PDF $P\color{red}{'}(x)$. One comment, two answers for such a simple question. Everyone else agrees.

Answer (score 1):

Your probability function $P(x)$ is apparently the cumulative distribution that is $P(x)=\mathbf{Pr[x}\le x\mathbf{]}$ so $P(x+dx)=\mathbf{Pr[x}\le x+dx\mathbf{]}\approx P(x)+P'(x)dx$, that is $P(x+dx)-P(x) = \mathbf{Pr[}x < \mathbf{x}\le x+dx\mathbf{]}\approx P'(x)dx$ where now $P'(x)$ is the probability *density*.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous probability distributions are defined by the probability *density*, which is a function $\rho(x)$ of the random variable $x$ defined such that the area under it's curve between $x_1,x_2$ is the probability $P(x_1<x<x_2)\equiv\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\rho(x)dx$. Note that for continuous distributions, the probability *at a point is zero*, as the (Reimann) integral vanishes (the area under the curve if $x_1=x=x_2$ is zero, there's no 'rectangle' you can draw). This is no more than saying that I cannot tell you the mass of a single point in a glass of water, but if you give me the density of water and fill a certain volume I can integrate the density over that volume and give you the mass. In other words, continuous probability distributions are useful only to calculate the probability for a *given range* of possible outcomes.

Now, assume that you ask 'what's the probability of finding $x$ in an infinitesimal neighbourhood of $x_0$, say $(x_0-\epsilon/2, x_0+\epsilon/2)$. Then, you'd have $$P(x\in(x_0-\epsilon/2, x_0+\epsilon/2))=\int_{x_0-\epsilon/2}^{x_0+\epsilon/2}\rho(x)dx\approx\rho(x_0)\epsilon$$

Since the density is approximately constant in infinitesimal interval, the same as a curved line is straight if you go close enough. You can recast this as

$$P\bigg(x\in\big((x_0-\epsilon/2),(x_0-\epsilon/2)+\epsilon\big)\bigg)\approx \rho(x_0)\epsilon $$

You can also write $\rho(x-\epsilon/2)$ if you like, but for small $\epsilon$ they're the same thing(do a Taylor expansion and see what happens as $\epsilon\to 0$).